# Google maps v2 wont appear when i downloaded my app from Play store

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2

My app runs perfectly wen i use eclipse the maps display but when i decided to download it to my phone from play store google maps wont appear.
Any help with this?

Comment: are you using the right api key for the release apk?

Comment: Dear Friend, Have you created a map key again after exporting APK with keystore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As posted in the comments, you need an API key tied specifically to your release key.  The API key you used while programming (through the debug mode, which used the debug key) won't work.  Once you have generated your release key, use that to generate a new Google Maps API key, and replace the existing one.

As expected, the new one won't work while debugging - you'll need to switch back to the debug API key should you need to run your app in debug mode again.

Comment: Thanks tats exactly wat I forgot to do